# How to add cell-padding or cell-spacing in ruby pdf-writer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, pdf-writer

I have seen an ocean of options in [pdf-writer](http://ruby-pdf.rubyforge.org/pdf-writer/) Simple-Table, but it doesn't seem to have the cell-spacing and cell-padding.

1) Is it implemented, did i miss it? If so, can you plz gimme a line of code.

2) If not implemented, is there any work-around?

Any help is appreciated.

THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PDF work, most likely, nowadays, you really want to work with prawn:
http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/